# General Solution of $y''+4y=\frac{3}{\sin(2t)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have taken a course in ODEs before, but have forgotten how to solve for certain particular solutions. I came across this differential equation recently and would like to solve for the general solution.

The equation is $y''+4y=\frac{3}{\sin(2t)}=3\csc(2t).$

I know how to solve for the homogenous solution as I should since I just take $r^2-4=0\implies r=\pm 2i$, so we have $y_h=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)$. I am really unsure of hot to solve the particular part of this ODE. I know that if this $\sin(2t)$ was on the numerator rather than denominator, then we simply plug in something like $y=At\cos(2t)+Bt\sin(2t)$ and solve for $A$ and $B$, however I have no idea how to solve this particular part with a cosecant term and would greatly appreciate any help in solving this.

Also, does anyone has any good resources that I can use to review what tricks to use to solve for the particular solutions of certain uncommon ODEs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this particular case you can try to use wolframalpha.com to find the solution and if you are willing you can get a subscription in which case they will also provide you with a step by step guide how to find such a solution. The solution they provide for this case is $y(t) = c_2 \sin(2 t) + c_1 \cos(2 t) - \frac{3}{2} x \cos(2 t) + \frac{3}{4} \sin(2 t) \log(\sin(2 t))$, wolframalpha should be sufficient for most ODEs but it is known to fail when too many variables are introduced.

Comment: @MartinvanIJcken I have seen this solution but have no idea where this $\log(\sin(\cdot))$ comes from. This is precisely why i am looking for explanation and I unfortunately do not have Wolfram Alpha premium.

Comment: In this case mathematica tells me to do some magic with a 'wronskian' - which I personally do not understand - you might know more about this than I do, and otherwise you could search for a wronskian. I am sorry that I am unable to help you much further.

Answer (score 4):

$$y''+4y=\frac{3}{\sin(2t)}$$
$$\sin (2t)y''\color{red}{+2\cos (2t)y'-2\cos(2t) y'}+4\sin (2t)y=3$$
$$(\sin (2t)y')'-2(\cos(2t)y)'=3$$
Integrate.
$$\sin (2t)y'-2\cos(2t)y=3t+C_1$$
$$\left ( \dfrac y {\sin (2t)}\right )'=\dfrac {3t+C_1}{\sin ^2(2t)}$$
$$ y(t)= {\sin (2t)} \ \int \dfrac {3t+C_1}{\sin ^2(2t)}\ dt$$

Note that:
$$ \int \dfrac {C_1}{\sin ^2(2t)}\ dt=-\dfrac {C_1}2\cot (2t) +C_2$$
For the second integral, perform an integration by part.

Comment: Wow, this was amazing. Do you normally try to find some simple way to solve strange ODEs like you did here and then resort to some standard method if you cannot find a trick or was this unique to this problem?

Comment: This differential equation is unique because it has no term in $y'$ ...Practice is the best school for math and especially for differential equations @mathim1881 But i try always to find simple ways to solve DEs

Comment: Elegant solution !

Comment: Thank you Claude @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be solved through variation of parameters. As it seems that OP is not familiar to (or has forgotten) this technique, let me demonstrate the idea. First, rewrite the ODE as

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \begin{pmatrix} y \\ y' \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} y' \\ y'' \end{pmatrix}
= \underbrace{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0 \end{pmatrix} }_{=\mathbf{A}} \begin{pmatrix} y \\ y' \end{pmatrix} + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3\csc(2t) \end{pmatrix}}_{=\mathbf{g}(t)}. $$

We know that the solution of the homogeneous equation $y_\text{h}'' + 4y_\text{h} = 0$, or equivalently

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \begin{pmatrix} y_\text{h} \\ y_\text{h}' \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} y_\text{h} \\ y_\text{h}' \end{pmatrix}, $$

is exactly $ y_{\text{h}} = c_1 \cos(2t) + c_2 \sin(2t) $, or equivalently,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} y_\text{h} \\ y_\text{h}' \end{pmatrix}
= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2t) & \sin(2t) \\ -2\sin(2t) & 2\cos(2t) \end{pmatrix}}_{=\mathbf{X}(t)} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

It is easy to check that $\mathbf{X}' = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}$, i.e., each column of $\mathbf{X}$ solves the homogeneous equation. Then we make an ansatz that the solution of the original, non-homogeneous equation takes the form

$$ \begin{pmatrix} y \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{u} $$

for some vector-valued function $\mathbf{u}$. Plugging this ansatz to the original equation,

$$ \require{cancel} \cancel{\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{X}\mathbf{u}' = \cancel{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{g}, $$

and so, the equation reduces to

$$ \mathbf{u}' = \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{g} =  -\frac{3}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \cot(2t) \end{pmatrix} $$

Integrating both sides,

$$ \mathbf{u} = -\frac{3}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 2t \\ \log\left| \sin (2t) \right| \end{pmatrix} + \mathbf{c} $$

for some constant vector $\mathbf{c}$. Therefore

$$ \begin{pmatrix} y \\ y' \end{pmatrix}
= \mathbf{X} \mathbf{u} 
= -\frac{3}{4} \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2t) & \sin(2t) \\ -2\sin(2t) & 2\cos(2t) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2t \\ \log\left| \sin (2t) \right| \end{pmatrix} + \mathbf{X}\mathbf{c}. $$

Note that $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{c}$ describes the general-solution term. Then reading out the first row of the product in the right-hand side yields

$$ y = c_1\cos(2t) + c_2\sin(2t) -\frac{3}{2} t\cos(2t) + \frac{3}{4} \sin(2t) \log \left| \sin (2t) \right|. $$

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to use [Variation of Parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx)

This is an algorithmic approach. Please see the examples (specifically Example $1$)

Here $y_1 = \cos 2t$ and $y_2 = \sin 2t$

Check that the Wronskian is $2$

The PI is given by

$$- \cos 2t \int \frac{\sin 2t}{2} \frac{3}{\sin 2t} dt + \sin 2t \int \frac{\cos 2t}{2} \frac{3}{\sin 2t} dt$$

This simplifies to $$-\frac{3t \cos 2t}{2} + \frac{3}{4} \sin 2t \ln|\sin 2t|$$
$$$$